# combobox doesn't return value in EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs5

I have the following combobox element:

```
editType = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    fieldLabel: 'Type',
    name: 'Type',
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'id',
    store: {
        fields: ['id', 'name'],
        data: [
            {id: '1', name: 'View'},
            {id: '2', name: 'Edit'},
            {id: '3', name: 'Admin'}
        ]
    }
})
```

when I try to submit my form I submit its value like this:

```
userType: editType.getValue()
```

The Problem is that if I don't choose anything from it, then it returns displayField value, i.e. `View`. If I choose something then it returns the valueField, i.e. `1`, `2` or `3`. If the user don't choose anything I want to return number value like I have set, not the label.

I have search about this but couldn't find where my problem is. I read the specification and it states that:

> comboboxElement.getValue() returns valueField
>
> comboboxElement.getRawValue() returns displayField

**Update**

I am loading combobox as a part of a panel form, i.e. when I click on a row form a grid I load that particular row in a form with method `myForm.loadRecord(clickedRow)`

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried your code, and if you don't select anything "editType.getValue()" return null, which is perfectly normal

Comment: I didn't mention that combobox and other fields are populated with `form.loadRecord()`

Comment: so you should show that part too